# Factorization of the ring $\mathbb{Z} [i]$ of Gaussian Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

Prove that if a pair of integers a and b is a solution to the equation
$$x^2 +y^2=n$$

Then $n$ factors $\mathbb{Z} [i]$ as the product $(a+bi)(a-bi)$

I understand that in $\mathbb{Z} [i]$ that $a^2 +b^2 = (a-bi)(a+bi)$. Im not sure how or what Im actually trying to prove.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's much else to do - as written, the problem seems to be to show that if $a^2 + b^2 = n,$ then $n = (a + bi)(a - bi),$ which as you already know follows just from expanding the product.